# Change colours of particular bars in a bar chart

Tags: r, colors, bar-chart

I've been creating some bar-charts and I was wondering is it possible to colour bars on a chart depending on whether they lie above or below the x-axis?

For clarification, this is the type of bar-chart I mean:

[image]

Ideally I would like to be able to colour the bars above a separate colour to those below so the graph looks more appealing, I've been searching but I can't find any method of doing this, can anyone help?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 34):

Here's one strategy:

```
## Create a reproducible example
set.seed(5)
x <- cumsum(rnorm(50))

## Create a vector of colors selected based on whether x is <0 or >0  
## (FALSE + 1 -> 1 -> "blue";    TRUE + 1 -> 2 -> "red")
cols <- c("blue", "red")[(x > 0) + 1]  

## Pass the colors in to barplot()   
barplot(x, col = cols)
```

If you want more than two value-based colors, you can employ a similar strategy (using `findInterval()` in place of the simple logical test):

```
vals <- -4:4
breaks <- c(-Inf, -2, 2, Inf)
c("blue", "grey", "red")[findInterval(vals, vec=breaks)]
# [1] "blue" "blue" "grey" "grey" "grey" "grey" "red"  "red"  "red"
```

[image]

Answer (score 21):

A `ggplot2` solution using `geom_bar` with `stat_identity`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x= seq_along(x), y = x)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(fill = x>0), position = 'dodge', col = 'transparent') + 
  theme_bw() + scale_fill_discrete(guide = 'none') + 
  labs(x = '', y = 'NAO Index')
```

[image]

`scale_fill_discrete(guide = 'none')` removes the legend, `position = 'dodge'` stops the warning that comes from  the default `position = 'stack'`.

Comment: how can I use colors like yours in barplot(t(as.matrix(mydf)), beside=TRUE, col=heat.colors(3)) ? Thanks

Answer (score 15):

One way is to index a vector of colours with a logical or factor variable (this is a common idiom in R.

```
set.seed(1)
NAO <- rnorm(40)
cols <- c("red","black")
pos <- NAO >= 0
barplot(NAO, col = cols[pos + 1], border = cols[pos + 1])
```

The trick here is `pos`:

```
> pos
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[11]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[21]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[31]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

which we coerce to numeric in the  `barplot()` call:

```
> pos + 1
 [1] 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2
[31] 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
```

The vector of `1`s and `2`s selects elements from the vector of colour `cols`, such that:

```
> cols[pos + 1]
 [1] "red"   "black" "red"   "black" "black" "red"   "black"
 [8] "black" "black" "red"   "black" "black" "red"   "red"  
[15] "black" "red"   "red"   "black" "black" "black" "black"
[22] "black" "black" "red"   "black" "red"   "red"   "red"  
[29] "red"   "black" "black" "red"   "black" "red"   "red"  
[36] "red"   "red"   "red"   "black" "black"
```

which is the colour passed on to each bar drawn.

In the code above I also set the border of the bars to the relevant colour, via argument `border`.

The resulting plot should look like this

[image]

Comment: +1 for the nice explanation, and esp. for the suggestion to color the border as well.

Answer (score 3):

I found this page while looking for help on how to colour individual bars in a bar chart according to a factor. I couldn't find any other source of information but thanks to this page, came up with this:

cols <- ifelse(df$Country == "Greenland", "green","blue")

It then gets passed into barplot in the usual way as described above:

barplot(x, col = cols)